# Firebase dynamic link not opening custom url if app not installed

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-dynamic-links

All functions of firebase dynamic link working fine but I want to make it like if app not installed then open website instead of playstore link

[image]

still it opens playstore link

Comment: instead of "Custom URL or Google Play Instance Experience", why don't you choose "Open the deep link URL in a browser"

Comment: I tried that but it says invalid dynamic link

Comment: then how do you know your dynamic link is working fine? how about make a simple flow to test that the dynamic link works first?

Comment: I never tried it open in browser always redirect on app side